# Mock Pony ORM entity

Tags: unit-testing, ponyorm

I'm trying to test a function like this:

```
    def whatever():
        return select(t for t in Team
                  for p in t.Players
                  if p.Age > 18)
```

Test:

```
@patch('path.to.my.function.Team', return_value=TeamFactory.create())
def test_whatever(self, mock_team):
    players = whatever()
```

But I'm getting this error:
*TypeError: Cannot iterate over non-entity object*

Any idea on how to create a fake entity and test the function?

Answer (score 1):

In order to overcome the error, `Team` and `Players` should be not classes, but instances of some `Mockup` class, with `__iter__` method which returns empty iterator. The simples implementation looks like:

```
class Mockup(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([])

Team = Mockup()
Person = Mockup()
```

Then you need to provide mockup implementation of `select` function that returns desired result

In PonyORM itself, entity classes like `Team` and `Person` have a metaclass `EntityMeta` which defines `__iter__` method for classes.